# Mojarra loses view parameter

Tags: jsf-2, post-redirect-get, mojarra

I am trying to implement post-redirect-get pattern in Mojjara. I have two pages with the same header and a search form in it.

Both pages have included in their common template these two codes

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="searchString" value="#{searchBean.searchString}" />
    <f:viewParam name="mutation" value="#{searchBean.mutation}" />
</f:metadata>
...
<h:form id="searchForm">
    <div class="search">
        <p:autoComplete id="autocomplete" minQueryLength="2" queryDelay="250" completeMethod="#{searchBean.complete}" value="#{searchBean.searchString}" />
        <p:watermark for="autocomplete" value="#{msg.search}" />
        <p:commandButton action="search?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true" value="#{msg.searchIt}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{searchBean.mutation}" value="#{facesContext.viewRoot.locale}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </div>
</h:form>
```

When I submit the form from `article.xhtml`, the url is `search.xhtml`, when I submit the form from `search.xhtml`, I get the expected URL with pattern `/search.xhtml?searchString=stringSearch&mutation=cs`

Am I missing something?

Edit: the backing bean uses some kind of combination between view and flash (bean is saved into both scopes and is retrieved fron the one, where it had survived). From debugging it seems that JSF get the params before they are saved in the bean (in the incorrect use case).

Comment: so, when you submits from `search` to `article` it works, but not the contrary?

Comment: when I submit the form in search.xhtml, it works as expected (redirect with parameters). When I submit the form in article.xhtml, i get only redirect without params.

Comment: it is, or not? (the form is the same for both pages, its in their common template)

Comment: I dont understand, where the answer is :-). You said, that the form must point to the same page - and I anwered, that it is pointing to the same page (search) :-). So i dont see any problem...

Comment: I was asking if the commandButton of both pages should be to the view search, and you said yes. currently. I was just asking to understand the situation.

Comment: There is no simple way to do GET (afaik). I am using a JSF component in the form, so I cant use simple form. If you know how to achive this, please post code and the bounty is yours :-).

Comment: I also got hit by this bug(?) . Oh how I wish there is already a solution!

Comment: If you find one (or find out that it is fixed), please keep me posted... I havent found a solution yet...